# MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff) - google GTM 400 error

Tags: mime-types, google-ads-api

I am trying to solve error from firefox console:

> The resource from
> “https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/973891309/?random=1655454537427&cv=9&fst=1655454537427&num=1&guid=ON&resp=GooglemKTybQhCsO&eid=375603261&u_h=1080&u_w=1920&u_ah=1040&u_aw=1920&u_cd=24&u_his=5&u_tz=120&u_java=false&u_nplug=0&u_nmime=0&sendb=1&ig=1&frm=0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gm.gama-sklep.com.pl%2F&tiba=Meble%20-%20Internetowy%20Sklep%20Meblowy%20Gama&hn=www.googleadservices.com&rfmt=3&fmt=4”
> was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch
> (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

In previous topics on this forum usually problem was with  script url and type but in this situation  above url is called from  google tag manager script which is delivered from google. Base script is typical for  gtm and looks like this:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
    (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({
            'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
        });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src =
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-NXQN6F4');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Similar situation is when i try to add remarketing tag  without gtm using js code from ads panel:

```
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: 482376610 -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-482376610"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-482376610');
</script>
```

Above code will also report 400 error + mime type error.

Is this a problem releated to server?

Comment: We're facing the same issue right now. Where you able to resolve this?